# Making a hyperlink only work IF JavaScript is disabled?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I have been researching and learning more and more about HTML 5, jQuery, CSS3, and the power of hiding and disabling certain elements when JavaScript is or is not disabled. (`<noscript>` tags)

My questions are,

1. How do I make a hyperlink **ONLY** work if **JavaScript is DISABLED?**
2. If **JavaScript is enabled**, how do I make sure that my **drop-down login menu displays INSTEAD** of following the hyperlink?

**HTML**

Simple enough, I hide my cart area and change the login link if the JS is disabled.

```
<!-- If JavaScript is disabled it will make the login link take you to a login page instead of a drop-down box. -->         
<noscript>
    <style>
        .login-form, .js-enabled{
            display: none;
        }
        .cart{
            top: -80px;
        }
    </style>                                
    <div class="cart">
        <a href="#" id="cart_img">
            <img src="img/bag.jpg" alt="Check Cart"
            onmouseover="this.src='img/bag-gold.jpg'"
            onmouseout="this.src='img/bag.jpg'">
        </a>
        <a href="#">Why HorseTack?</a> | 
        <a href="#">About</a> | 
        <a href="#">Contact</a> | 
        <a href="http://www.LOGINPAGELINK.com">Login</a>
    </div>
</noscript>
<!-- End JavaScript text -->

<div class="cart js-enabled">
    <a href="#" id="cart_img">
        <img src="img/bag.jpg" alt="Check Cart"
        onmouseover="this.src='img/bag-gold.jpg'"
        onmouseout="this.src='img/bag.jpg'">
    </a>
    <a href="#">Why HorseTack?</a> | 
    <a href="#">About</a> | 
    <a href="#">Contact</a> |                           
    <a href="#" class="login-box">Login</a>
        <div class="login-form">
            <form class="login-frm">
                <label><input type="text" placeholder="Username"></label>
                <label><input type="password" placeholder="Password"></label><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Login"><br>
                <a href="#">New User?</a>
            </form>
        </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

This makes the login-box slide down (just to avoid taking people to a login page unless they have to)

```
    // Login Box Pop-Up
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".login-form").hide();
    //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
    jQuery(".login-box").click(function()
    {
    jQuery(this).next(".login-form").slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

What I would like instead of having that `<noscript>` tag and the content duplicated, just a way for the hyperlink to only work when there is no JavaScript.

I have already set the page up to let users know when their JS is disabled (like Stack Overflow has done)

Any questions about my question (hopefully I wasn't vague?) ask!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I make a hyperlink ONLY work if JavaScript is DISABLED?
>   If JavaScript is enabled, how do I make sure that my drop-down login menu displays INSTEAD of following the hyperlink?

Write a JavaScript function that causes the menu to be displayed. Make sure that it captures the first argument (which will be the event object).

Bind the function to the link as [an event handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Call [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) on the event object.

```
function (event) { /* display menu then ... */ event.preventDefault(); }
```

---

> `<noscript>` tags

There are almost always the worst solution to a problem. Be [progressive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Comment: You forgot the inevitable "Tad da!" ^_^

Comment: So the event.preventDefault(); would go at the end of my drop-down slide menu's code?

I am trying to understand, and thank you for the references as well since those are really helpful.

Comment: NVM got it.
Thank you again :D

Answer (score -1):

You could show the link, and if javascript is enabled, hide it.

Comment: If the link is hidden, the user can't click on it to make the menu appear.

Comment: That is true.  However, OP stated, "How do I make a hyperlink ONLY work if JavaScript is DISABLED?".  I took this to mean that the link should only be shown if (and only if) javascript is disabled.  So, I figured that the link would be visible unless there was a javascript function to explicitly hide it - which would mean the link is visible and available when javascript is disabled.

Comment: I apologize. I should of said make a hyperlink work like normal when JS was disabled otherwise display a drop-down login menu. Sorry!

Comment: No worries, I was just attempting to answer the question as was posed :).

Answer (score -1):

You can put the link inside a div, and if JS is enabled, remove the link and put an event to that div
Like:

```
<div class="link-holder">
    <a href="page.html">Link</a>
</div>
```

And jQuery:

```
$(document).ready()
{
    $('.link-holder').text('').click(function(){
        displayLogin();  //assuming displayLogin() has your function to, well, display the login
    });
}
```

Comment: Div elements are not designed to be interactive. Doing this will break any kind of HUI device that isn't pointer based (so for anyone using a keyboard, breath switch, etc including most people who depend on screen reading software).